# sed -i is writing in reverse order! Why?

Tags: shell-script, sed

Why is sed writing to my file in reverse order?

---

I need to read a text file (`old_file.txt`) that contains the following data:

**what's in the file `old_file.txt`:**

```
1.00
2.00
3.00
```

I have a second file, which contains:

**what's in the file `new_file.txt`:**

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
EEEE
FFFF
GGGG
```

Now, I need to move the cursor to the `nth` line of the file `new_file.txt`, and insert everything that was in `old_file.txt`, like this:

**What I need:**

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
1.00  <-- 
2.00  <-- 
3.00  <--
DDDD
EEEE
FFFF
GGGG
```

But I get:

**What I get:**

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
3.00  <--
2.00  <--
1.00  <--
DDDD
EEEE
FFFF
GGGG
```

---

This is my code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

line=3 # line that I need (exemple)

while read x 

    do
        sed -i "${line}a\ $x" new_file.txt

    done < old_file.txt
```

**I don't know why writing happens in reverse order!**

Comment: [Stop, sed i!](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2020/08/06/stop-sed-i/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's happening because your loop appends `1.00` after `CCCC`, then appends `2.00` after `CCCC`, then appends `3.00` after `CCCC`.

To get the order you want, you could instead **i**nsert `$x` before the (n+1)th line - however you don't need a shell loop here at all if you use **r**ead from the file directly:

```
sed -i "${line}"'r old_file.txt' new_file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative, without sed.

```
#!/bin/bash

line=3
{ head -${line} new_file.txt ; cat old_file.txt; tail +$((line+1)) new_file.txt ; }
```

In other words copy the first `$line` lines of `new_file` to the output, then the whole of `old_file`, then the rest of `new_file`, from `line+1`.